# Binary trees in C++ using references

Tags: c++, reference, tree, binary-tree

I wish to implement a binary tree using references instead of using pointers (which is generally what you tend to find in every book and every website on the internet). I tried the following code:

```
class tree_node {
private:
    tree_node& left;
    tree_node& right;
    data_type data;
public:
    void set_left(tree_node&);
    // ... other functions here
};

void tree_node::set_left(tree_node& new_left) {
    this.left = new_left;
}
```

I get the following error:
error C2582: 'operator =' function is unavailable in 'tree_node'.

I know I can easily implement it using pointers but I would like to keep my solution elegant and free of pointers. Can you tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Who said that "elegant" means "free of pointers" ? And if it can be done easily with pointers, why to avoid them?

Comment: Nah. I thought using references would look better. Anyway, I have been stupid to overlook the fact that references cannot be modified after initialization. Thanks a lot for the prompt replies. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't change the object that a reference refers to<sup>1</sup>; once you initialize a reference, it always refers to the object with which it was initialized.

You should use pointers.  There is nothing wrong with using pointers for this (it's clean using pointers as well because parent nodes own their children, so cleanup and destruction is easy!)

<sup>(1) Well, you *could* explicitly call the object's destructor and then use placement new in the assignment operator implementation, but that's just a mess!</sup>

Comment: Using something like shared_ptr makes the implementation even cleaner!

Comment: @monoceres: Well, `shared_ptr` is probably inappropriate since it's a _tree_ (meaning a node should have a single owner--its parent). But `scoped_ptr` would be a good choice.

Comment: Even good old `std::auto_ptr`... just because it is not perfect, it does not mean that it is useless --as long as you are aware of the pitfalls, that is :)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot assign to references. What you're trying to do can't be done... without a huge amount of bending.. (you'd essentially destroy a node and create a new one each time you want to modify it.)

There's a good reason why all those other people use pointers.

Answer (score 2):

References aren't just pointers with shorter syntax. They're another name for the actual object they refer to, even when used as the lhs of an assignment.

```
int i = 3;
int j = 4;
int &ref = i;
ref = j;
std::cout << i << "\n"; // prints 4: i itself has been modified, 
                        // because semantically ref *is* i
```

That is, `ref = j` has the same effect as `i = j`, or the same effect as `*ptr = j`, if you had first done `int *ptr = &i;`. It means, "copy the contents of the object `j`, into whatever object `ref` refers to".

For the full lifetime of `ref`, it will always refer to `i`. It cannot be made to refer to any other int, that is to say it cannot be "re-seated".

The same is true of reference data members, it's just that their lifetime is different from automatic variables.

So, when you write `this.left = new_left`, what that *means* is, "copy the contents of the object `new_left` into whatever object `this.left` refers to". Which (a) isn't what you mean, since you were hoping to re-seat `this.left`, and (b) even if it was what you meant, it's impossible, since `this.left` has reference members which themselves cannot be reseated.

It's (b) that causes the compiler error you see, although (a) is why you should use pointers for this.

Answer (score 1):

References in C++ don't work the same as references in other languages. Once a reference is set, at construction time, it can't be changed to anything else.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is to use boost's [shared_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) class instead of a reference. This will free you of the concern for managing the pointer's deallocation. You may also be interested in [Boost's graph library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/graph/doc/table_of_contents.html).